# Finding the coordinates in Cartesian coordinate system

Tags: math

I have 3 points in Cartesian coordinate system. I know the inter distance between the points. I also know the distance of the points from the origin. Is it possible to know the coordinates of the points?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about practical computer programming but rather belongs on [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) once the questioner has added more of his own work and explained just where he is stuck.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: No, because you use an infinite number of coordinate systems where the relative distances are all valid.  The best you can do is pick one origin and set of axes  and calculate relative to that.  You can use one point as the origin, define the three points in a single plane, and let the third coordinate be the cross product of two vectors in the plane.

Answer (score 1):

This isn’t enough information to determine the locations of the points.

Imagine that you have found one possible location for those three points. Take the points and rotate each of them around the origin by the same angle θ. This preserves all the distances between the points and between the points and the origin, but gives a different solution to the original set of constraints.

Comment: Why do you answer a question that is so completely off-topic and shows no effort at all from the questioner? (Your reputation shows that you know this site well--I really would like to know your reasoning.)